# What argument passed?

Tags: c++, function, parameters, arguments, double

I am learning `C++ language`, but much confused about a little thing, that is
below I have putted some code of making a square of an integer. But I am not understanding the treatment of `x` in `raiseToPow` function. Here `double x` is an argument taking the value from calling function and passing to `x` in for loop. So how it makes square of that integer passing from `x`. Please guide me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double raiseToPow(double x, int power){
   double result;
   result = 1.0;
   for (int i = 1; i <= power; i++)
   {
        result *= x;
   }
        return (result);
   }
 main()
   {
   double x;
   int i;
   cout << "Enter the Number: ";
   cin >> x;
   cout << "Enter the Power: ";
   cin >> i;
   cout << x << "Raise to power " << i << " is equal to " << raiseToPow(x , i);

   }
```

Comment: Do you understand what exponentiation actually is?

Comment: yes i know Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams. But i am actually confused about the value that argument passing? I am not sure what it is passing and whom and why it is doing this.. :(

Comment: @Grzegorz Szpetkowski Whatever it is.. but i am just asking about the solution and little help to understand the basic programming skill.. i have to complete my study assignment in this matter

Comment: The exponentiation function is defined as F(x, p) = x^p. Right? So x and p are the passed arguments, and F(x,p) is the returned value. So what is the question?

Comment: @Eugene Sh. For example i am entering the value of x = 2 in main(). It passed in raiseToPow function and there x assignment as 2. So when it multiply by result, does not it would be as " 1.0 * 2" that answer will be 2. So when again the loop runs and it will again multiply by 1.0 which is result and stop. So how it return as 4 to function?

Comment: So your real question, I guess is what is `result *= x;` Well, it is equivalent to `result = result * x`. Now it should be clearer, that you are not multiplying by 1 every time.

Comment: oooppppsss... i got it.. i forgot that it is assigning new value to result for first time and second time it will be changed.. Thanks a lot Eugene Sh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`double x` is the base of the exponentiation x<sup>power</sup>.

The function uses the definition x<sup>power</sup> is 1 multiplied by x power times. Thus 2<sup>3</sup> is 1*2*2*2 and 4<sup>5</sup> is 1*4*4*4*4*4. So `double result` is set to be 1, then the for loop executes power times, each time multiplying `result` by `x` and storing that back in `result`.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is C++, not C, the logic is the same.
You pass in a number(x) and its exponent(power). The value of x is multiplied 'power' times.
For example, if you want to know the value of 2 raised to the power of 3, you would pass 2, 3 to the function raiseToPow

The statement

```
    result*=x
```

is the same as

```
    result = x*result.
```

So, the first time through the loop, result would just be the value of x (2, in this example). The second time through the loop, result*=x would multiply the value of x(which is 2) times the value stored in result (which, for now, is also 2). The third and final time through the loop, result *=x would multiply x times the value stored in result (which now is 4).

The value of 2^3=8, and that is what the value stored in the variable result is, so the value 8 is returned from the call raiseToPow(2,3).